# Alignment algorithm dynamic programming with gap

Tags: algorithm, optimization, alignment, dynamic-programming

I wrote a dynamic programming alignment algorithm. I wish to align two lists of peaks that have been extracted from two different signals. Lists of peaks are dataset with two colums, two features: time for the peak and area of the peak. Since peaks are from two different signals, both lists contains no exact matches. However, both lists of peaks have some peaks in common (~two third), that is to say peaks that are close both regarding time and area.

In my first DP algorithm, i rely on a distance calculation that takes time and area into account. I iterate over peaks in the shortest peak list, and calculate their distance to some peaks in the other dataset. I fill in a score matrix with these distances and i go backward to find back the ooptimal path (with minimum distance). This is working perfect IF I WANT TO ASSIGN ALL PEAKS IN SHORTEST LIST TO PEAKS IN LARGEST LIST. However, it is not working if gap are allowed, that is to say if some elements in shortest data set have no match in largest data set.

Which refinement of DP could enable to handle this type of problems? What other algos are at hand to handle these problems ?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I am following in [sequence aligning in the field of bio-inofrmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment), it is we do take gaps into consideration, Can you provide your recursive formula and a small test case that shows where it fails for you?

Comment: I don't have much knowledge in the area you have mentioned here- and have been trying to refresh my knowledge in Discrete Fourier Transform..but have you looked at DFT? Would the convolution of the two signals help you- if you graphically plot the convolution- the high values in the convolution might correspond to peaks in both the signals.